# How to deny access to menu items that aren't expected

Tags: hooks, navigation, page-controller

I want to find a way to make requests to `hook_menu` that I don't expect be denied. For example I have defined a menu like this:

```
$items[$my_url] = array(
  'title' => $my_title,
  'page callback' => 'my_page_callback',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'page arguments' => array('hot'),
  'file' => 'includes/my.pages.inc',
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
$items[$my_url . '/hot'] = array(
  'title' => 'hot',
  'page arguments' => array('hot'),
  'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items[$my_url . '/new'] = array(
  'title' => 'new',
  'page arguments' => array('new'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items[$my_url . '/rising'] = array(
  'title' => 'rising',
  'page arguments' => array('rising'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'access callback' => TRUE,
);
$items[$my_url . '/controversial'] = array(
  'title' => 'controversial',
  'page arguments' => array('controversial'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'weight' => 10,
);
```

How can I make sure `$my_url/something` doesn't return the `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` page but instead returns a 403 page or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The following `MENU_CALLBACK` worked to deny wild card matches for me.

```
$items[$my_url . '/%'] = array(
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'page callback' => 'drupal_access_denied',
  'access callback' => TRUE
);
```